# No operating system found Error 1962

Tags: boot, uefi, system

Have read quite a few topics on this but found not solution for me. I am a Windows Guru, no Linux experience. Building a Ubuntu box for my grandson.

I can boot and select the USB with Ubuntu install. I can run the trial. I completely formatted the hard drive and it was clean and single partition. I then installed and all seemed to work well until reboot and Error 1962.

This is an older (12 years?) Lenovo tower but decent specs. 8 GB RAM, 2 TB hard drive, I7, etc. I find nowhere in the BIOS to set either legacy or UEFI. Nor anything "CSM" as some threads suggest. I set the hard rive to be first in boot order. There is no other operating system installed. A drive map now shows 2 partitions a smaller, if I recall 32 GB and the rest an empty partition.

Seems like some sort of MBR or boot loader may be missing.

I have not yet tried setting BIOS to defaults. First thing tomorrow. But if that does not work, how do I start to sleuth further. Is is possible this box cannot run UBUNTU? I'd be very surprised but saw some reference to "approved to run Ubuntu" or similar wording.

Can you help?

Thanks so much.

~Bob

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.0.4 LTS. Since I did not download nor create the USB, I will do that tonight and try again tomorrow. Then will try DEFAULT BIOS settings. I'll also get the Lenovo ThinkCentre model #. Then I will try the boot repair utility of no progress yet and come back and post results.

---

Today: Built a new Ubuntu install USB. All looked fine until reboot and the Error 1962 again.

Nothing in BIOS refers to CMS, UEFI, Legacy. Very simple BIOS. Still trying to find Lenovo model #.

Ran 32 bit Boot Repair Disk. Complained about UEFI and said I should try 64 bit, perhaps saying with UEFI, which does not exist. I will try the 64 bit, but not hopeful.

It really feels like it is not finding an MBR of any kind. At a loss for how to continue. Need to run errands and back tonight.

Thanks.

---

Lenovo H520s
Machine Type: 4746
MTM: 47461FU

---

Long discussion here with someone with identical machine and issue. Most above my head:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2466985

---

Boot Repair Disk 64 says it did a number of fixes including GRB, biut no luck. Same error. Went to installer, checked EFI and renamed the grubx64.efi to bootx64.efi. No luck.

Someone said to try reformatting to GPT? That's new to me. Is that worth a try?

---

I am slowly understanding and OldFred's advice may be it. But I think folks assume I know how to hget to partitions in Ubuntu, then how to mount before I even can find EFI folder. Took a lot of trial and error and googling to get there.

I have hopes for this one today. Shall see.

---

Tried editing EFI as per oldfred's instructions. No joy. But I "sometimes" see this error on bootswith the test usb in, not booting from HD. I belive that to be true. Says something to the effect of Firmware Bug : No firmware reserved region can cover this....

Does that help?

---

Comment: Error 1962 sounds like a *firmware* message to me, but you've made it somewhat difficult for us, given no actual *software stack* clues as to what Ubuntu product or release you're asking about. Ubuntu offers 4 different installers, selected at download time (*by the ISO you download & use*) but you've not told us what product, nor what release of that product you elected to use (*nor with installer if you had choices for product/release*)... eg. Are you asking about Ubuntu 23.10 Server? Ubuntu Core 22? Ubuntu 20.04 6 LTS Desktop etc (*at a minimum, some Desktop releases have two choices too*)

Comment: For your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release, did you verify the ISO after download to ensure it's valid; validate the ISO write to media? (*or check logs; I consider this cheap insurance*), how did you write ISO to media - ie. a simple clone or a reformat option provided by writer (*which can cause installed systems to fail to boot if not used appropriately for your hardware/firmware settings.. ie details do matter*).  FYI: Personally I just *clone* iso to media, as it'll then work on legacy device (pre-uEFI), uEFI & Secure-boot uEFI too

Comment: Thanks. Its Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I did not download the release so unsure what options were presented.  If I try to find where it was downloaded from and redownload, which should I select?

It was given to me on USB. The trial works. The installer "appears" to work until a reboot.

If you would like me to step back, please give me steps.

Thanks.

Comment: Please also add details of your hardware, you say *Lenovo tower*, but being specific with model details are helpful too.

Comment: OK, I told you I am a Linux newbie. Just ask.

Desktop. 

Where might I find the log files? And if comments are not the propere place to continue the post, where should I be posting?

Do not know the details on tower tonight. I do know its circa 2010 and ran Windows 10 just fine, albeit slow. I7 quad core. 8 GB RAM. Unsure what bios version or Lenovo model number. Will find out.

Comment: [SOLVED] Error 1962: No operating system found. Lenovo K430  only boot Ubuntu, rename files
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243715 Some systems only want to boot "Windows Boot Manager". If i7, should be UEFI, but early UEFI may work better with BIOS install. If no Windows still better to use gpt partitioning, but then need a 1MB unforatted partition with bios_grub flag for grub to install. If that old,Kubuntu (mid-weight) or a lightweight flavor may be better. But specs should be good enough for Ubuntu. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: Thanks. But this predates W520's ( I have one :) and this BIOS has no such options. The most sparse BIOS I have ever seen.

Comment: Maybe ask  MAFoElffen in the forums for help.  That thread you posted seemed to have the problem go away, but no solution!  I'd avoid logical volumes, use a /boot partition right after the EFI and last resort, boot the hard disk root off a USB!  Check that you firmware is the latest, the overlap is pretty common, never noticed it cause any problems though.